# Is the notion of injective a.e. in the image well-defined for Sobolev maps?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a nice open, connected, bounded subset (say with smooth boundary), and let $p \ge 1$.

I want to know whether the following notion of "injective a.e. in the image" is well-defined:

Say that $f \in W^{1,p}(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$ is **injective a.e. in the image** if $|f^{-1}(y)|=1$ for almost every point $y \in \mathbb R^n$.

Is this notion well-defined, or does it depend upon the representative we choose for $f$ (which formally is an equivalence class in $L^p$ satisfying some additional requirements...).

I guess that since we can freely change $f$ on a subset of measure zero, we can just take any uncountable subset of measure zero $\Omega_0 \subseteq \Omega$, and send it to whatever we want in $\mathbb R^n$. Somehow I am not sure if this really shows that this notion is not well-defined.

(Do we need the continuum hypothesis here? If we knew any uncountable subset had the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ then we could just map it bijectively onto $\mathbb R^n$ "twice" or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a bad choice of language here, and your counterexample would work.  There is no need for continuum hypothesis here because we know there is a Cantor set that will work.

The definition of injective a.e. is: there exists a negligible set $S$ outside of which $f$ is injective.  In other words, for any choice of representative $f$, there exists a negligible $S\subset\Omega$ such that $f\vert_{\Omega\setminus S}$ is injective.  Note there is no mention of the image here, and it works as advertised.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought. However, can you elaborate on how do you use this Cantor set? I guess that you meant to take a Cantor set of measure zero in the domain, and map it to a subset of positive of measure in the codomain, right? but how do you do that without the continuum hypothesis? Do you map your Cantor set onto a "fat" Cantor set? (do we know they have the same cardinalities without the continuum hypothesis?)

Comment: We know $\Omega$ contains some copy of $I^n$ and $I$ contains a scaled copy of the middle-third Cantor set $K$ (which is null in $I$, so $K^n$ is null in $I^n$).  We also know that $K$ bijects with $\mathbb{R}$ (just use Schroeder-Bernstein).  So we can take each direction separately and biject this copy of $K^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$.